# Add two step colors to point using ShaderMaterial in threejs

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am writing a shader for shadermaterial in three.js.

I want to add color to a point such that its border should be in black and inner filled color should be original vertex color(e.g. red).

This can be done by using texture but I don't want to use texture.
I have applied a gl_PointSize to increase the point size.

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/14532/ BTW: What is your reason for not just using a texture?

Comment: Yes I am looking for the same but I don't want it in gradient...Want an sharp border.
The reason behind not using texture is performance degradation.
I am having more than 20,000,000 points, so using texture obviously decrease the performance of rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it an approach like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/14545/

The idea is to use the [step()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) function to produce a sharp rectangular border for each point. You can change the thickness of the border by altering the second parameter of the function.

```
vec2 c = abs( gl_PointCoord - vec2( 0.5 ) ) * 2.0; // move origin to center
float f = step( c.x, 0.6 ) * step( c.y, 0.6 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Mugen, This is exactly what I am looking for.